# Huawei HG8245H MAC Address Change (Clone)

Tags: networking, wireless-router, modem, ip-address, mac-address

My last router had an option to clone/change my router's MAC Address (did this in  order to change my public IP Address for x,y,z reasons)

On this specific router "Huawei HG8245H"(which is a 2in1 Router + Modem) can't find the option anywhere for this; looked everywhere on the net and I only encounter ways to change internal IP.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following way, if it does not work. Maybe this Huawei HG8245H device does not allow us to change the MAC address.

From the article :[How to change the MAC address of my modem/router/gateway ?](https://www.speedguide.net/faq/how-to-change-the-mac-address-of-my-modemroutergateway-416), we can see:

All network hardware is assigned a special unique identifier, the Media Access Control (MAC) address during production by its manufacturer. It helps identify the device on the network. Sometimes it is necessary to change that id and use a particular MAC address to be able to connect to your ISP. Below is a general guideline on how to do so on many routers/gateways and ADSL/VoIP/cable modems.

Here are the necessary steps to change the MAC address on your device:

1. Get to the web admin interface of your device.
   You will have to find your router/modem's IP address. If you're connected to it, you can drop to command prompt and type: ipconfig (the IP address of your "Default Gateway" should be the router/modem's IP). Some of the most common IPs are:
   Motorola SB modems: 192.168.100.1
   Other modems/routers: 192.168.1.1
   You can also lookup the default IP and login information of your device in our hardware database.
2. Find the correct menu to change your MAC address 
   It is usually in "Setup > Advanced", you're looking for a menu called "MAC Address Clone". This should let you enter your own MAC address, it is designed to clone the MAC address of your network card. Note that this menu may not be available on all devices, or it may only be available to be provisioned by your ISP. In such cases, you may have to call them and ask them to "reprovision" your modem.